# Подключение Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

В качестве практики по PHP, решил написать блог.

Необходимо передать объект шаблонизатора Smarty в методы моих классов, которые отвечают за генерацию страниц.

Правильным ли будет такое решение: в основном контроллере с помощью конструктора создаём объект смарти и дальше уже унаследуем класс основного контроллера в другие классы?

```
// Основной контроллер
abstract class Controller
{
    protected $smarty;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Подключение Smarty
        require_once(SMARTY_DIR . 'Smarty.class.php');        
        $this->smarty = new Smarty;
        $this->smarty->template_dir   = SMARTY_DIR . 'templates/';
        $this->smarty->compile_dir    = SMARTY_DIR . 'templates_c/';
        $this->smarty->config_dir     = SMARTY_DIR . 'configs/';
        $this->smarty->cache_dir      = SMARTY_DIR . 'cache/';
    }
}

// Контроллер статей
class ArticleController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // Подключение шаблона статей
        $this->smarty->display('article.tpl');
    }
}
```

Comment: куда вы наследование потеряли во втором контроллере? а так да, корректное поведение, однако имеет смысл вынести инициализацию смарти в отдельный метод и его уже вызывать потом.  и подключать пхп-файлы где то внутри методов не есть хорошо. Названия директорий лучше вытащить в конфиг.

Comment: да и в целом, сделайте так чтобы конечный контроллер не знал о наличии смарти. сделайте базовый метод `display()`, который будет вызывать смарти. и `set` для установки переменных